# Issue with FunctionalTestComponent (Mule 3.2.1)

Tags: mule

I would expect a `<test:component />` to be equivalent to

```
<component>
    <spring-object bean="FTC" />
<component>
```

where the FTC bean uses the `FunctionalTestComponent` class. That is, I would expect the two configurations below to pass the functional test shown further below.

config with `<test:component />`

```
<mule ...>
    <vm:endpoint name="EntryPoint.Name" path="EntryPoint.Path" />
    <simple-service name="service" endpoint-ref="EntryPoint.Name" >
        <test:component />
    </simple-service>
</mule>
```

config with spring bean using FunctionalTestComponent

```
<mule ...>
    <vm:endpoint name="EntryPoint.Name" path="EntryPoint.Path" />
    <spring:bean id="FTC" class="org.mule.tck.functional.FunctionalTestComponent" />

    <simple-service name="service" endpoint-ref="EntryPoint.Name" >
        <component>
            <spring-object bean="FTC" />
        </component>
    </simple-service>
</mule>
```

test

```
@Test
public void aTest() throws Exception {
    final MuleClient client = muleContext.getClient();
    client.send("vm://EntryPoint.Path", "1", null);
    assertEquals("1", getFunctionalTestComponent("service").getLastReceivedMessage());
}
```

The config with `<test:component />` passes the test. However, the one with the FTC bean does not. In fact, the run with the FTC bean shows an exception in the logs:

```
********************************************************************************
Message               : Component that caused exception is: DefaultJavaComponent{service.commponent}. Message payload is of type: String
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. null (java.lang.NullPointerException)
  org.mule.tck.functional.FunctionalTestComponent:215 (null)
2. Component that caused exception is: DefaultJavaComponent{service.commponent}. Message payload is of type: String (org.mule.component.ComponentException)
  org.mule.component.DefaultComponentLifecycleAdapter:359 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/component/ComponentException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.mule.tck.functional.FunctionalTestComponent.process(FunctionalTestComponent.java:215)
    at org.mule.tck.functional.FunctionalTestComponent.onCall(FunctionalTestComponent.java:108)
    at org.mule.model.resolvers.CallableEntryPointResolver.invoke(CallableEntryPointResolver.java:50)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************
```

Any idea what I could be doing wrong? I am using Mule 3.2.1

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out. The definition of the bean is missing one attribute `init-method=
"initialise"`. This detail seems to be missing from the [documentation](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Functional+Testing#FunctionalTesting-AdditionalExample%3AEventCallbackWithaSpringComponent). Hence, the definition of the bean should be:

```
<spring:bean id="FTC"
    class="org.mule.tck.functional.FunctionalTestComponent" init-method="initialise" />
```

Comment: By the same token I imagine *<singleton-object class="org.mule.tck.functional.FunctionalTestComponent"/>* shown in the doc would fail too :( Generally speaking, it's better to use test:component anyway.

Comment: @David: You are right. I later realized that I did not need to have a separate bean for my purposes.